# How to work on Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar

Tags: magento-2.1

I had uploaded Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar inside my root folder.I'm new to this topic.please share me that how can show the category sidebar in frontend.

Comment: Share the exact question regarding what you are asking for the help & for the frontend development may this link helps you
`http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html`

Answer (score 0):

you should add it on `app/code/Sebwite/Sidebar` folder (if you don't have folders just create them) after that use below commands:

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento cache:flush
```

then you can see the configurations in admin panel
if you have any other questions keep calm and ask me!

**Note:** use full version of extension